# Как преобразовать вложенный объект в другой вид?

Tags: javascript

Есть такой вложенный объект:

```
[
  {
    ID: 1,
    VALUE: 'Телефоны и гаджеты',
    CHILDREN: [
      {
        ID: 2,
        VALUE: 'Смартфоны',
        CHILDREN: [
          {
            ID: 2,
            VALUE: 'Смартфоны iPhone'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

И я хочу преобразовать его к такому виду:

```
 {
  id: 1,
  name: 'Телефоны и гаджеты',
  children: {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Смартфоны',
    children: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Смартфоны iPhone'
    }
  }
}
```

```js
      const data = [
        {
          VALUE: 'Телефоны и гаджеты',
          CHILDREN: [
            {
              VALUE: 'Смартфоны',
              CHILDREN: [
                {
                  VALUE: 'Смартфоны iPhone',
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]


function getProp(el) {
  if (Array.isArray(el.CHILDREN)) {
    getProp(el.CHILDREN[0])
  }
   return el
}

const result = getProp(data[0])
console.log(result)
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как написать правильно рукурсивную функцию, которая пройдется по всем объектам и вернет нужную структуру?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = [
  {
    ID: 1,
    VALUE: 'Телефоны и гаджеты',
    CHILDREN: [
      {
        ID: 2,
        VALUE: 'Смартфоны',
        CHILDREN: [
          {
            ID: 2,
            VALUE: 'Смартфоны iPhone'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]


function getProp(el) {
  const resultObj = {};
  resultObj.id = el.ID;
  resultObj.name = el.VALUE;
  if (Array.isArray(el.CHILDREN)) {
    resultObj.children = getProp(el.CHILDREN[0]);
  }
  return resultObj;
}

const result = getProp(data[0])
console.log(result)
```